# How to detect whether app is going to be killed?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to send a message to the server when the app is going to be killed, (either by the user quitting the app or the system killing the app). How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at your `AppDelegate.swift`. The answer is in there.

Comment: Can it be accessed in anywhere other than the app delegate though, e.g. via a notification

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationwillterminatenotification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle using `NotificationCenter` like that 
`NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillTerminate` [see here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification.name/1623061-uiapplicationwillterminate)

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(test), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillTerminate, object: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

Handle code here

```
 func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

  NotificationCenter.default.post(name:Notification.Name("appwillTerminate"), object:"")


}
```

Comment: Is it possible to access this in anywhere other than the app delegate? Like a via a notification or something

Comment: You can post a notification yourself from this method.

Comment: Keep in mind that execution of this method is really fast, so some complex processes  maybe will not be executed.

Comment: Updated check it